# The class of left serial rings is closed under extensions

Tags: ring-theory, modules

A class $S$ is closed under extension if given an ideal $I \subseteq R$ such that $I\in S$ and $R/I\in S$, then $R\in S$.  A ring $R$ is left serial if it is a direct sum of left uniserial rings.  Prove that the class $$S_R:=\{R:R~\text{is left serial composed of only finite left uniserial rings}\}$$ is closed under extensions.

We call a ring left uniserial finite length of if it has a unique composition series of finite length, that is, $R \supset L_1\supset L_2\supset\cdots\supset L_m = 0$ is the lattice of left ideals of $R$.

Comment: What does "composed of only finite left uniserial rings" mean?  A finite product of left uniserial rings? or the rings are finite sets?

Comment: Hrm, well if true, that's interesting.  It's a bit odd I can't find anything like that in Puninski's book on serial rings though. Where does the problem come from, incidentally?

Comment: I have added the definition for left uni-serial rings.  So in this $R$ is a finite direct sum of such left uni-serial rings

Comment: Oh, finite **length**, i.e. Artinian. That makes sense too now.  But what's the source?

Comment: It is an exercise in which I am trying out on various classes of rings.  I am testing classes closed under extensions and those which are not.  I have tested on Artinian rings and it worked.  But now, extending to serial rings (over Artinian) is a problem.

Comment: So *you* are the source of the exercise, and you do not really know if it is true or not. That is fine, but you should mention it.

Comment: Do you require $R$ and/or $I$ to have an identity?

Comment: Yes, $R$ is unital.

Comment: .........and $I$?

Comment: I mean that I'm asking if *everything* in $S_R$ has identity or not.

Comment: Yes, $S_R$ is a class of unital left serial rings described above.

Comment: I kind of want to post a bounty to this question, but until you acknowledge in the body that you actually don't know if it's true, and that you've come up with the problem yourself, I won't be putting a bounty on it. As written, it pretends that it is already proven somewhere, and I don't want to waste anyone's time if it isn't actually true.